# To be able to add pagesize dropdown using jquery in Kendo grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

My question may seem redundant but what I need is ability to add\show pagesize dropdown in the grid pager using jquery. I need this on runtime and not specify the pager settings in the html. Consider the following example

[Jsfidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zL6J/)

Replace the html in the above link with the following

```
<div id="grid"
    data-role="grid"
    data-sortable="true"
    data-selectable="true"
    data-pageable="{ refresh: true }"
    data-columns='[
                { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name"},
                { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name" },
                { field: "City" } ]'
    data-bind="source: info">
</div>
```

Add the javascript after -- kendo.bind($("#grid"), { info: ds});

```
var gridPager = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
gridPager.pager.options.pageSizes = [10,20,50]; // This code line is not working expected
```

I tried various options but couldn't find a solution to this problem. May be I am missing something very small.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
kendo.bind($("#grid"), { info: ds });
var gridPager = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

var dropDown = $("#grid .k-pager-sizes").find('select').data("kendoDropDownList");
var datalength = dropDown.dataSource.data().length;
for (var i = 0; i <= datalength; i++) {
    var itemToRemove = dropDown.dataSource.at(0);
    dropDown.dataSource.remove(itemToRemove);
}
dropDown.dataSource.add({ text: "10", value: "10" });
dropDown.dataSource.add({ text: "12", value: "12" });
dropDown.dataSource.add({ text: "15", value: "15" });
dropDown.select(0);
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. I am not sure if you used the html i provided above. The html is different from the one used in JSFiddle link. Your dropdown comes out as null simply because at html there is no dropdown added. That is the whole issue I am facing, I need to add dropdown dynamically. Let me know if you need more clarification